# How to find out style of NSUserNotification during run-time? Or force close an alert?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, notificationcenter, nsusernotification

According to [OS X Mountain Lion Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/Foundation.html):

> "The user has ultimate control over what notifications are displayed, and the style (banner, alert, etc). There is no mechanism to override the user preferences."

Even though all I want to do is "downgrade" from alert style to banner style... Fine. **But can I at least find out whether a notification is of alert or banner style inside the didActivateNotification method?**

When the alert is a banner (which is what I want), clicking its contents is the only possible action, and this both triggers didActivateNotification method with notification.activationType value of `NSUserNotificationActivationTypeContentsClicked` and closes the notification banner. I want my app to respond to this action by opening an internet URL.

When the user chooses alert-style notifications, clicking the alert contents also generates didActivateNotification with the same value of `notification.activationType`, but it stays on screen instead of going away (it only goes away when the Action button is pressed, and notification.activationType has a different value then). *I don't want my app to trigger an action repeatedly for the same alert notification, in case the user clicks the content area of an alert notification.*

**An alternative solution would be to force the alert notification bubble to dismiss when the user clicks its contents.** Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the notification with the following:

```
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotification:notification];
```